# Use awk to format date field

Tags: text-processing, awk

How to do I convert date format from "09-12:36:10" into "09-Month-Year 12:36:10", replacing “Month” with the current month name (three-letter abbreviation) and “Year” with the current year (four-digit), using awk? 
For example, change "09-12:36:10" to "09-JUL-2018 12:36:10".

Comment: Is the "July 2018" a constant, or should it be the current month? Does it have to be with awk?

Comment: @ilkkachu No July 2018 is not a constant.

Comment: you want current month and year to be inserted?

Comment: @sivaPrasath Yes.

Comment: Why does it have to be `awk`?

Comment: @roaima It doesn't I suppose, but that what I use in the past.

Comment: I'd also consider this to be a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/454565/how-to-do-i-convert-the-contents-to-the-below-format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do I convert the contents to the below format?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/454565/how-to-do-i-convert-the-contents-to-the-below-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply,

```
echo 09-12:36:10 | awk -F '-' -v date="$(date +"-%b-%Y " )" '{ print $1date$2}'
```

If you are keen to have month in upper case:

```
echo 09-12:36:10 | awk -F '-' -v date="$(date +"-%b-%Y " )" '{ print toupper($1date$2)}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how robust you are needing this, but here is a start:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS = "-"
}
{
    print $1 "-MONTH-YEAR", $2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Awk (`gawk`), you can use its built-in `systime` and `strftime`

```
gawk -F'[-]' '{print $1, strftime("%b %Y", systime()), $2}'
```

Ex.

```
$ echo '09-12:36:10' | gawk -F'[-]' '{print $1, strftime("%b %Y", systime()), $2}'
09 Jul 2018 12:36:10
```

If you need the abbreviated month in upper case, try `%^b` e.g.

```
$ echo '09-12:36:10' | awk -F'[-]' '{print $1 strftime("-%^b-%Y", systime()), $2}'
09-JUL-2018 12:36:10
```