# How to do I convert the contents to the below format?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

```
pid        name          tid        mod         state   data
-------------------------------------------------------------------------  
39523      srv0051_0001_0  39642 20-10:59:28 Working 820000:500196:500077 
43137      srv0051_0005_0  43156 20-10:59:28 Working 820000:4250501:840057
43895      srv0051_0006_0  43903 20-10:59:28 Working 820000:4250501:840057
47523      srv0051_0009_0  47547 20-10:59:28 Working 600005:4250501:4250846
48841      srv0051_0010_0  48851 20-10:59:28 Working 600005:4290000:4290000
58182      srv0051_0020_0  58188 20-10:59:28 Working 820000:4250501:840057
8297       srv0079_0008_0  8316  20-10:59:27 Working 600005:3070001:3050012
```

```
pid,name,tid,mod,state,appnbr,request,tasknbr,appctx,username
39523,srv0051_0001_0,39642,09-JUL-2018 12:36:10,Working,820000,500196,500077
43137,srv0051_0005_0,43156,09-JUL-2018 12:36:10,Working,820000,4250501,840057
43895,srv0051_0006_0,43903,09-JUL-2018 12:36:10,Working,820000,4250501,840057
47523,srv0051_0009_0,47547,09-JUL-2018 12:36:10,Working,600005,4250501,4250846
48841,srv0051_0010_0,48851,09-JUL-2018 12:36:10,Working,600005,4290000,4290000
58182,srv0051_0020_0,58188,09-JUL-2018 12:36:10,Working,820000,4250501,840057
8297,srv0079_0008_0,8316,09-JUL-2018 12:36:10,Working,600005,3070001,3050012
```

This data is being gathered by running the below command:

```
spsmon -state working -snapshot > /root/file.txt
```

What I have so far:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print 
"pid,name,tid,mod,state,appnbr,request,tasknbr,appctx,username"} NR>5 
'!/Process/' '!/ProcessModules/' '!/ProcessEvoke/' {print 
$1","$2","$3","$4","$5","gensub(/:/,",","g",$6)}' /root/file.txt > 
/root/file.txt
```

I'm mainly confused on how to change the mod column into my desire date format.

Comment: what does `20-10:59:28` is meant?

Comment: That's what a call to be in lazy mode...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using GNU Awk, and taking the missing month and year from current time:

```
gawk '
  BEGIN{
    OFS=","
    print "pid,name,tid,mod,state,appnbr,request,tasknbr,appctx,username"
  }
  NR>2 {
    split($4,a,"-")
    $4 = a[1] strftime("-%^b-%Y ", systime()) a[2]
    gsub(/:/,",",$6)
    print
  }' /root/file.txt
```

or omit the file and use it in a pipe

```
spsmon -state working -snapshot | gawk '...'
```

---

Ex.

```
$ gawk '
  BEGIN{
    OFS=","
    print "pid,name,tid,mod,state,appnbr,request,tasknbr,appctx,username"
  }
  NR>2 {
    split($4,a,"-")
    $4 = a[1] strftime("-%^b-%Y ", systime()) a[2]
    gsub(/:/,",",$6)
    print
  }' file.txt
pid,name,tid,mod,state,appnbr,request,tasknbr,appctx,username
39523,srv0051_0001_0,39642,20-JUL-2018 10:59:28,Working,820000,500196,500077
43137,srv0051_0005_0,43156,20-JUL-2018 10:59:28,Working,820000,4250501,840057
43895,srv0051_0006_0,43903,20-JUL-2018 10:59:28,Working,820000,4250501,840057
47523,srv0051_0009_0,47547,20-JUL-2018 10:59:28,Working,600005,4250501,4250846
48841,srv0051_0010_0,48851,20-JUL-2018 10:59:28,Working,600005,4290000,4290000
58182,srv0051_0020_0,58188,20-JUL-2018 10:59:28,Working,820000,4250501,840057
8297,srv0079_0008_0,8316,20-JUL-2018 10:59:27,Working,600005,3070001,3050012
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that there is nothing apparent in the source data that seems to be the origin of `09-JUL-2018`, I have hardcoded it.  That said:

```
$  awk -F"[ \t]+|[:]" 'BEGIN { OFS=","; print "pid,name,tid,mod,state,appnbr,request,tasknbr,appctz,username" } NR>2 {print $1,$2,$3,"09-JUL-2018",$7, $8, $9, $10}' input
pid,name,tid,mod,state,appnbr,request,tasknbr,appctz,username
39523,srv0051_0001_0,39642,09-JUL-2018,Working,820000,500196,500077
43137,srv0051_0005_0,43156,09-JUL-2018,Working,820000,4250501,840057
43895,srv0051_0006_0,43903,09-JUL-2018,Working,820000,4250501,840057
47523,srv0051_0009_0,47547,09-JUL-2018,Working,600005,4250501,4250846
48841,srv0051_0010_0,48851,09-JUL-2018,Working,600005,4290000,4290000
58182,srv0051_0020_0,58188,09-JUL-2018,Working,820000,4250501,840057
8297,srv0079_0008_0,8316,09-JUL-2018,Working,600005,3070001,3050012
```

Comment: `12:36:10`  is missing and I hope it shouldn't be hardcoded. The question is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
 sed -e 's/  */,/g;s/:/,/g;/^-/d;s/data/appnbr,request,tasknbr,appctx,username/1;s/20-10:59:28/09-JUL-2018 12:36:10/g' /root/file.txt
```